# Attribute Error: Reading metadata of lidc-idri dataset metadata

Tags: xml, metadata, attributeerror

While runnning this code line:
To get the patient ID I have run the following line:
patient_id = root.find(".//PatientID").text
Output received is as follows:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
How to solve the error?